# Why does a justified <p> element ignore a right margin?

Tags: css, margin, justify

I have a div that contains a paragraph, a list and a right-floated div.

The parent div has a text-align:justify; property.

I am giving the p an (all-around) margin of 20px, but for some strange reason, the margin gets ignored on the right side of the paragraph. I tried it on the ul and the same thing happens.

The margin is not ignored if I do not justify the text inside the parent div.  (But I do want it justified).

The floated div has a margin:0; so I guess this is not a collapsing margins issue.

The floated div is a fixed dimension (pixels) div and it is empty, except for a background image.

I also tried to specify the margin by margin-right:20px; and it did not work...

I know I could resolve it by just adding a left margin to the floated div. But I would like to know what is happening.

Here's the code I'm using (I only edited the class names).

The CSS:

```
.parentDiv {
    position: absolute;
    width: 660px;
    height: 350px;
    z-index: -1;
    background-color:#4F4F4F;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align:justify;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.foatedDiv {
    float:right;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;

}

.parentDiv p {
        margin:20px;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="parentDiv">
 <div class="floatedDiv" style="width:234px;background-image:url(images/jp01.jpg)"></div>

  <strong><a href="someAnchor">Anchor</a></strong>

  <p>Sope paragraph that I cannot understand why ignores its right margin and is driving me crazy.</p>

  <strong>Some Topic</strong>

  <ul>
     <li>Some long item long enough to show there is no right margin.</li>
     <li>Some long item long enough to show there is no right margin.</li>
     <li>Some long item long enough to show there is no right margin.</li>
     <li>Some long item long enough to show there is no right margin.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And this is what I get:

[image: some nice alt text here]

Comment: You put a lot of effort into this question, so +1

Comment: The example text doesn't match the screenshot and there is definitely CSS being used that is not mentioned above, contrary to what's claimed and I don't see the problem described in Webkit or Gecko (when I correct the typo in the CSS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because that image on the right side is floated to the right. It is applying your margin, you just can't tell. That paragraph actually expands all the way to the right under that image, just the content box doesn't. Your margin-right needs to be the width of that image **plus** 20px in order to indent it out 20px from the image.

**What your margins actually look like:**

[image: example]

While the floated element pushes your **content** to the left, the actual **physical box** still expands behind that. To push the content out more, you have to account for all that space taken up by the image. One way to do that is to add it's width to your margin on the right, like this:

```
.parentDiv p {
    margin: 20px 254px 20px 20px; /* 234 + 20 = 254 */
}
```

See the [solution on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rcgUZ/2/).

Comment: Or just give the floating `<div>` a margin-left, I think.

Comment: @sdleihssirhc: Yes, that would work too and would be the preferred method if the content is meant to wrap down under the image.

Comment: But the text is shown completely (no part of it is hidden behind the image). 

Why does it behave like that? Doesn't really make sense to me.

Can I do it a different way? (I do not want to add the image width to the margin because I will repeat these boxes several times with different width images...

And I did not want to give the div the left margin because as you can see the idea for the image was to have no margin, this margin is related to the text only...

Comment: @Ozkar: I added an image to explain how the margin is applied.

Comment: @animuson, Thanks I see now where my margin went (I tried removing the image and I can see the margin does show when the text reaches the right end of the containing div).

Why does it work like this though? Does it make sense to have a box expand where content cannot...?

Comment: @Ozkar: An element which is `display: block` always takes up the maximum available width, even if the content cannot. I have no idea the *exact* details as to why it's implemented this way, I just know of this oddity from my experience in CSS.

Comment: Well I guess I'll have to work around it, I got some good tips.
Thanks for explaining where the margin went! Now I can sleep :P

Answer (score 1):

The margin is being applied, but because the image is wider it's being counted as "good enough".

To fix this problem, add `padding: 0.01px;`. Intuitively this makes no difference, since you can't see a hundredth of a pixel, but the padding should force the margin to apply.

Comment: Where should that padding go? I tried it in the containing div, in the floated div and on the p and none worked...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you noticed the spelling error?

```
**.foatedDiv** {
  float:right;
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
}
```

Should be **floatedDiv**

I believe the code does what you require. However on the inline style where you reference the image add margin-left: 20px and it should fix it.

If you are further in doubt you could wrap your title and unordered list in another div and handle padding and text alignment etc from within that div.

Comment: Thanks, I edited those names for the example, but they are right on my original code.
Adding an inner wrapping div sounds good too.

Comment: Ideally if it was me, I would have your wrapper parent div and a div containing the text and a div containing the image. OR a wrapper div with a background with the image and your text div inside with the parameters you require - HTH